# Can an LED be used in paralell of a free wheel diode?

Tags: led, inductance

Can an LED be used in paralell of a free wheel diode?
All circuit is powered by a 12V alternative.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs47lw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think it can be used like that; when power (12 V) gets off; then the power kept in the inductor has to get out in C1 and trough D1 is a little part of the power crossing D2?

Comment: 100 ohms seems a little low for a 12V supply and a normail indicator LED

Comment: it hurts my eyes to look at that schematic ... what is the reason why the ground link between L1 and D1 is not lined up with the rest of the ground net?

Comment: Please clarify what _alternative_ and _gets off_ means. Your LED in not in parallel with the diode in your schematic.

Comment: When do you want the LED to be ON? Please answer for/to clear the confusion :)

Comment: @User323693 See his last paragraph - he is saying he wants flyback energy to light the LED - which it will not do with either polarity.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon agree with you too.. I think this is the most recent famous question in creating confusion :)

Comment: Francois - people are spending time trying to help you and have asked questions that need answering. Please help people to help you by answering their questions.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not as shown.

With the LED polarity shown the LED lights when power is provided and is OFF during the flyback cycle.
The reverse voltage across the LED (Vr) is low during flyback due to D1 so LED is protected.

If you reverse LED polarity it has the correct voltage during flyback to light BUT D1 clamps it to about 0.5 to 1 V so LED does not light.
On forward cycle LED has Vr of 12V applied which will damage or destroy many LEDs.

IF you want an LED to light during flyback you need to

- reverse polarity,
- remove D1 or replace it with a zener
- or add series R to D1 to allow voltage to increase to >= LED Vf,
  and add a reverse diode across D1 to protect it during 12V applied portion of cycle.

---

Note that the time constant of the LC components used is and unusual ratio of 1 uF and 1 nH. (Not the more likely 1 mH or 1 uH, but nH)

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit as drawn doesn't even make sense if you wanted to use D2 as a flyback diode because it's facing the wrong direction, and the R1 defeats the purpose of a flyback path.

But no. The biggest reason being that LED cannot withstand 12V in reverse.

Other reasons are more about LEDs not being optimal for the purpose with slow switching speeds, and high forward voltage drops.

EDIT: I think I misunderstood your question. You're not asking if you can use an LED as a flyback diode, right? You're just asking if you can have an indicator light in parallel with a coil and flyback diode? In which case, yes that works fine as long as your resistor is large enough to limit the current for the voltage being applied.

Comment: Ok so LED must be used on lower voltage elsewhere in circuit  & never in this part. Thanks.

Comment: @francoisP See edit.

Comment: ust asking if you can have an indicator light in parallel with a coil and flyback diode?  exactly @DKNguyen

Comment: LED lights on forward cycle and not on flyback. On flyback D1 clamps reverse voltage on LED. LED is NOT a flyback energy indicator. Reverse LED and diode clamps available flyback voltage. In non flyback part of cycle LED is exposed to possibly fatal Vr (some dislike high Vr at even tiny currents). Yes?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Hmmm, a cap in parallel with the LED might help a bit with that...maybe...

Comment: Note also the time constant and unusual ratio of 1 uF and 1 nH. (Not the more likely 1 mH or 1 uH, but nH)

Answer (score 0):

assuming L1 is something like a relay coil or electromagnet that has some significant real resistance and normally operates on a DC supply, them yes such a led would work

The flyback diode would provide sufficient reverse polarity protection to the LED.

probably 1K would be better than 100 ohms if that's an indicator LED and not a high power one illumination LED.

Comment: LED lights on forward cycle and not on flyback. On flyback D1 clamps reverse voltage on LED. LED is NOT a flyback energy indicator. Reverse LED and diode clamps available flyback voltage. In non flyback part of cycle LED is exposed to possibly fatal Vr (some dislike high Vr at even tiny currents). Yes?

Comment: huh? did you comment on the wrong answer?

Comment: No. But I MAY be wrong :-) (as ever). All answer so far seem wrong (strangely) (makes one wonder if one's brain is in backwards today :-) ). He clearly wants LED to be driven by flyback power. As shown its polarity is wrong. Reverse it and it will be clamped by D1 on flyback cycle so not light and will perhaps die on fwd cycle as Vr is now excessive. yes?

Comment: "clearly" ??? I didn't see that and still don't

Comment: He says: " ... when power (12 V) gets ***off*** ; then the power kept in the inductor has to get out in C1 and ***trough D1 is a little part of the power crossing D2?***..." -->  ie he wants the LED to be powered by the flyback voltage. | BUT the flyback polarity is wrong as shown AND even if the LED was reversed the voltage available is then clamped by D1's Vf. Or, is my brain in backwards today, as above ? :-)

Comment: Also - at present the LED "clearly" [tm] lights on the forward (+12V applied) cycle.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fysI2s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Original and redrawn circuit.*

> Can a led be used in parallel with a free wheel diode? All circuit is powered by a 12V alternative.

Yes.

> I think it can be used like that; when power (12v) gets off; then the power kept in the inductor has to get out in C1 and trough D1 is a little part of the power crossing D2?

If the power is switched off then C2 will supply current to L2 and the voltage will decay slowly. This will reduce or eliminate the inductive "kick" that would happen if C2 is not there.

If C2 is not there then D2 will allow the inductor current to decay without a voltage spike.

The LED will operate as normal.

Comment: LED lights on forward cycle and not on flyback. On flyback D1 (or D3) clamps reverse voltage on LED. LED is NOT a flyback energy indicator. Yes?

Comment: Correct. I knew it wasn't coming out right as I wrote it. Feel free to edit. It's getting late in Ireland.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.